# selecting a specific column in a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having the dataframe below:

```
library(pedquant)
cny=md_forex('usdcny')


head(cny)                                                                                                                                                 
$usdcny
     symbol   name       date    open    high     low   close
  1: USDCNY usdcny 2019-11-05 7.03001 7.03005 6.98776 6.98910
  2: USDCNY usdcny 2019-11-06 7.00824 7.00825 6.98995 6.99827
  3: USDCNY usdcny 2019-11-07 6.99685 7.01899 6.96794 6.97183
  4: USDCNY usdcny 2019-11-08 6.97665 6.99330 6.96865 6.99277
  5: USDCNY usdcny 2019-11-11 6.99536 7.01128 6.99211 7.00809
 ---                                                         
769: USDCNY usdcny 2022-10-28 7.25647 7.28390 7.22543 7.27225
770: USDCNY usdcny 2022-10-31 7.27600 7.32509 7.27289 7.31670
771: USDCNY usdcny 2022-11-01 7.33395 7.35534 7.26380 7.27740
772: USDCNY usdcny 2022-11-02 7.30845 7.31260 7.27717 7.29623
773: USDCNY usdcny 2022-11-03 7.34282 7.35168 7.31241 7.33906
```

I am trying to select the closing price column by doing cny$close & cny[,7], however, the two ways are not working. May I know what should I do from here? Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like `cny` is a list containing a data table called `usdcny`. Perhaps try `cny$usdcny$close` ?

Comment: *"the two ways"* are what ways exactly?